# Can I make Make arrange error messages it prints in parallel mode?

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have simple question, I compile a C program with flag -j

```
make -j4
```

How I can make all four processes write error messages successively (one error after another)?   Currently, when I start `make -j4`, I get errors then some ©mpilation commands, then some errors again.  It is not readable!  Is there sometihng to assist me?

```
zile.c: In function 'zile':
zile.c:12: error: 'milojko' undeclared (first use in this function)

zile.c:12: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
zile.c:12: error: for each function it appears in.)

zile.c:13: error: 'djole' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [zile.o] Error 1
/opt/toolchains/arm-uclibceabi-9260-big/usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc -I/usr/xenomai/include -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -Wall -pipe -D__XENO__ -I/opt/toolchains/arm-uclibceabi-9260-big/usr/include/ -O3 -Wall   -c -o testSine.o testSine.c
testSine.c:7: error: expected ')' before 't'

make: *** [testSine.o] Error 1
```

What I want is something like this:

```
error from process one
error from process four
error from process three
error from process two
```

, without commands mingling with errors.

Comment: It looks like you have some dependency problems, can you post your Makefile?

Comment: @Tim: no, it does not look like dependency problems.

Comment: I need to get error messages, I need to show them to user ( I am developing kind of IDE), errors is not problem, problem is that processes write errors random errors and calls. Is there flag for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. No real help on this point. As you know, the `-j` option starts as many different processes as required to fasten compilation (provided that dependencies allows).

These processes are completely unsynchronized. `make` simply control when it starts the processes, and wait for them to finish. `make` does not synchronize the output of all these various processes, it is not even desirable as it would slow every compilation process down.

To avoid printing the commands, you can use the `-s` (or `--silent`) option when calling make. But it will not prevent to have the output of the various compilations occurring in different processes to be interleaved.